# Angular 2 support for SAP backend

Tags: .net, angular, sap-basis

I would like to know the angular version 2 support with SAP as backend database .
Also let me know the Pros and cons of using angular 2 with SAP .

Comment: Will that be feasible?

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct support for Angular. The main cons is the lack of support for Typescript.

The best solution would probably be to use grunt tasks as described on the SAP documentation :
https://www.sap.com/canada/developer/tutorials/webide-grunt-plugins.html

Then you could use the tutorial for Angular JS  :
https://www.sap.com/developer/tutorials/angular-getting-started.html

The pros and cons depend on your objectives. You will have access to all the angular components (material, aot, tests...) but you might not be able to use Fiori components.

Keep in mind that you are working on a WebIDE, ng  commands will not be available outside of grunt tasks.

Comment: Thank for your comment

Comment: Also I would like to know the technical feaibility of using HIGHCHARTS with Sap database in .NET

Comment: I don't know HIGHCHARTS but you can use the .Net Connector.
I have not tested it on .Net 4.7 but it should work. You can then call abap functions. https://help.sap.com/doc/saphelp_crm700_ehp02/7.0.2.17/en-US/4a/097b0543f4088ce10000000a421937/content.htm?no_cache=true